# Django multi server application

Tags: python, django, orm

I am currently developing an application in Python using Django in which users can upload files to a remote server.

Here is the way I will proceed :

1. User upload the file to the remote server (which can be a Django app either)
2. The remote server get the file and validate this
3. The remote server has to record the file in the SQL database

Problem is that the remote server has not the models that the initial Django app has. So, remote server can not use Django objects with the foreign keys.

I thought about many solutions :

1. Try to synchronize models from the Django app with the remote server (but if I make a modification on the models on Django app, I have to re-synchronize every remote servers - which can be annoying if I have a lot of servers)
2. When the remote server has to record the file in SQL database, the remote server make a HTTP request to the Django app server with information about the file to save. In that way, Django app manage all SQL queries - but I can have many HTTP request, so is it a good solution?

I don't know how to manage this problem, so if you have a solution, tell me

Comment: You put files into a database? The best solution would be to distribute files between Django servers (and keep them in fs).

Comment: No, I don't put files directly in database. I save information about files on my database such as filename, filepath, user who upload the file, upload date, etc.

Comment: OK, so you're saying that two different servers use the same database, they are both written in Django but they use different models? And another question: what do you need the remote server for? Can't your Django app save that info directly into db?

Comment: I have not written the server yet, but in a concern to be compatible it will be written in Django. Problem is that I have to copy models from existing app to remote server (and if I have a lot of server it will be difficult to manage). Remote server make some operation on the file and I need it in order to prevent overload from the main server. File is uploaded directly on the remote server, so I don't have access to information about the file from the main server... Hoping it is clear to you, now :-)

Comment: It's a bit clearer now. :) But you are using some kind of repository, right? Is it a problem to simply download files (models) from your repository? I mean you still have to do that in order to launch remote servers' code. You can even write some kind of script to automate that process. It's definitely better then making additional requests, i.e. solution `1` seems to be better.

Comment: P.S. Managing lots of servers is always tricky.

Comment: Yes I use Git, it would be easier. Thank you for your answer and your help :)